# How to get both base64 imageobject and image location/name in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am using camera.getPicture and i need the base64 image object and the file name . As per my understanding i can get only one the base 64 image object or the location of the image. How do i get the imageobject and the name of the image file ?

Comment: By using fileuri u can the image name

Comment: yes but the camera.getpicture allows me only to get either the base64 image object or the path not both. ie dataurl or fileuri

Answer (score 2):

You can set Camera.destinationType to FILE_URI to get the location of the image and then use the readAsDataURL function of the FileReader API to get a base64 representation of the image.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader

Or you can set the uri to the src of an image tag, not sure what you're trying to do next with your image object.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the image path first by setting `Camera.destinationType` to `FILE_URI`, then use this [plugin](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64) to get its base64 encoding